# Can I call Bazel from Java code without installation?

Tags: java, bazel

Can I call Bazel from Java code without installing Bazel?

Is there a "bazel.jar" with a callable Java API?

I am extracting dependency information (include paths and defines) for C-files from bazel build files. This is information is then fed into my IDE's c code indexer.

The extraction parses the output from a bazel query. Right now this requires Bazel to be installed on the machine. The bazel query is then run as an external process started from Java code.

The question is: Is there a .jar and a Java API that allows for running the query  directly without the need to install Bazel?

Answer (score 1):

No, Bazel has no Java API, and I don't know about any standalone query tool.

[Buildifier and Buildozer](https://github.com/bazelbuild/buildtools) are tools that parse BUILD files. Perhaps you could modify one to use as a basis for a standalone query tool.

They are written in Go and you don't have to install Bazel to run them. (You may need Bazel to build them though.)